# ListView not showing result from JSON

Tags: android, json, listview

I have been using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) to learn how JSON, PHP and MySQL works together. I've got it going pretty good becuase I can add rows to the database, and I can see from my LogCat that I also can display all rows from the database. The problem is that the ListView isn't showing anything at all. Just black.

This is my all_products.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- Main ListView
     Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
-->
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my AllProductsActitivy.java:

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {
 
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://81.xxx.xxx.xxx/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

I get this from the LogCat as well, not sure what it means:

```
10-10 17:09:00.235: W/System.err(20177): org.json.JSONException: No value for products
10-10 17:09:00.255: W/System.err(20177): at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
10-10 17:09:00.255: W/System.err(20177): at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
10-10 17:09:00.255: W/System.err(20177): at com.sandtdevelopment.testjson.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProduct    sActivity.java:139)
10-10 17:09:00.255: W/System.err(20177): at com.sandtdevelopment.testjson.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProduct    sActivity.java:1)
10-10 17:09:00.255: W/System.err(20177): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-10 17:09:00.255: W/System.err(20177): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-10 17:09:00.255: W/System.err(20177): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-10 17:09:00.255: W/System.err(20177): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-10 17:09:00.255: W/System.err(20177): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-10 17:09:00.255: W/System.err(20177): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-10 17:09:00.260: W/System.err(20177): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-10 17:09:00.570: E/SpannableStringBuilder(20177): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans   cannot have a zero length
10-10 17:09:00.570: E/SpannableStringBuilder(20177): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans   cannot have a zero length
```

I can't really figure out why it isn't working. As I said above, I can see that the JSON is working because it shows in the LogCat, but nothing is showing up.

Something obvious for you guys?

Thanks!

Comment: The first line of your stack trace looks like its throwing an exception

Comment: One thing to note, in your AsyncTask, you don't need to "runOnUiThread" in onPostExecute. onPreExecute and onPostExecute already run in the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrongly defined the key of the `private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";` in your code.

In your JSON response its sending the array as  `product` not `products`. That is why while parsing the response its throwing error . `org.json.JSONException: No value for products`

**EDITED:**

Change your keys as below:

```
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "test1";
private static final String TAG_PID = "PID";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
```

Comment: I cannot find where it says `product`?

Comment: In the declaration part of the your activity.

Comment: Change your string `private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";` to `private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "product";`.

Comment: But where is JSON sending it as `product`? Just so I know what went wrong. Didn't work.

Comment: In your tutorial link check out `The json response for the above file will be

When successfully getting product details

{
    "success": 1,
    "product": [
        {
            "pid": "1",
            "name": "iPHone 4S",
            "price": "300.00",
            "description": "iPhone 4S white",
            "created_at": "2012-04-29 01:41:42",
            "updated_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: But that's only what they have named their columns in the database, I get this result in LC: `10-10 17:35:57.239: D/All Products:(31478): {"success":1,"test1":[{"PID":"1","ph_number":"0763196376","name":"andreas"},{"PID":"2","ph_number":"0340660509","name":"Alma"},{"PID":"3","ph_number":"025022088","name":"Juni"},{"PID":"4","ph_number":"654236","name":"test"},{"PID":"5","ph_number":"0735830991","name":"Caroline"}]}`

Comment: If you are getting this result then you should define the keys accordingly to parse this result as well. Whereas in your code you have defined key for `PID` as `pid`. Make sure keys are casesensitive to parse json response so define the keys accordingly to get values.

Comment: Totally agree with @GrIsHu . As the first line of the log says, the json keys are wrong and throw an exception. You name the array as "test" and your product ids as "PID", just keep loyal to your own namings.

Comment: "test" is the name of the database, and yes the product id is "PID". Don't see the problem with that? I get the results to the LC but it doesn't show on the display in the app? So I suppose the JSON part is working, because that would end when the data from the database is fetched?

Comment: Its absolutely working but its not parsing the values of your json because of wrong keys.

Comment: Hmm, ok I definitely understand what you mean but I cannot find where I've named the keys wrong. I'll keep looking!

Comment: You are absolutely right! I had messed up the "products" "test1", and also "name" had to be "NAME". Now it works! Thank you for helping a beginner. ;)

Comment: Happy to help you. All the Best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after setListAdapter.

From Android documentation:

**notifyDataSetChanged()**

*Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.*

Comment: If I add that after `setListAdapter(adapter);` I get this error _The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}_

Comment: I mean this: 
`setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Got this error instead: _The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter_